# How to prove that $E(\frac{\hat{E}^T\hat{E}}{n-q}) = \Sigma$

Tags: regression, self-study, mathematical-statistics, multivariate-analysis

So quick explanation:
This is a multivariate statistics problem (specifically for multivariate regression). n is, as always, the sample size. q is the number of independent variables. Sigma is the covariance matrix of $e_i$. E is the error matrix. The bold is for vectors. E.g. $\bf{1}$ is a vector of 1's.
Y is the $n$x$p$ matrix of the dependent variables for n observations and p dependent variables $y$.

---

My skill with this is lacking.

I can get this to,

$$E[Y^T (I-H) Y] = \Sigma$$ but have no clue how to introduce $\Sigma$

OK. But the book offers a hint.
It states that,
$$E(\hat{e}^T\hat{e}) = (n-k)\sigma^2$$

and suggest that this can be solved using another problem in the book so I'll show what was proven in that:

$$E(x^TAx) = E(tr(xx^TA)) = tr(\Sigma A) = \mu^TA\mu$$

$$\sigma^{-2}E(x^TAx) = tr(A) = p-1$$
given that $\mu = \mu \bf{1}$ $\Sigma = \sigma^2 I$ and $A = I -\bf{11^T} p^{-1}$

---

Let me know if you need anything else. I really want to figure this out but this is very difficult for me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please define all notations and the complete model. E.g., what is H? Also provide reference to "the book". The equation $\mu=\mu\mathbf{1}$ sounds wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Let us define the model as $y = X\beta + u$ where $X$ is $n \times q$ and $u$ is the $n \times 1$ error vector.

First let us consider $\hat{E} = y - \hat{y}$.

This is equal to $\hat{E} = y - \hat{y} = y - X(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty = (I - P)y$

where $P = X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$.

Then, we can show trivially that $P$ is a projection matrix i.e. $P^T = P$ and $PP = P$ and this is left to the reader to check.

Then as $y = X\beta + u$ we can say that $\hat{E} = (I-P)(X\beta + u) = X\beta -X(X^TX)X^TX\beta + u - Pu = X\beta - X\beta + (I-P)u = (I-P)u$.

Then, as $P$ is a projection matrix, so is $(I-P)$, hence $(I-P)^T(I-P) = (I-P)(I-P) = (I-P)$.

Then if we consider $\hat{E}^T\hat{E} = u^T(I-P)^T(I-P)u = u^T(I-P)u$ by the above.

Then as $u$ is $n \times 1$, $u^T$ is $1 \times n$ and so $\hat{E}^T\hat{E}$ is a $1 \times 1$ scalar.

Therefore $\hat{E}^T\hat{E} = tr\{\hat{E}^T\hat{E}\} = tr\{u^T(I-P)u\} = tr\{(I-P)uu^T\}.$

Then taking expectations of both sides we have that $E[\hat{E}^T\hat{E}] = E[tr\{(I-P)uu^T\}] = tr\{(I-P)E[uu^T]\}$ as $I-P$ is a constant.

Then as we assume $E[u] = 0$ we know that $E[uu^T] = var[u]$ and as we assume $Var[u] = \sigma_0^2$ we have that $E[uu^T] = \sigma_0^2$.

Hence $E[\hat{E}^T\hat{E}] = tr\{(I-P)E[uu^T]\} = tr\{\sigma_0^2(I-P)\} = \sigma_0^2 tr\{(I-P)\}$.

Then $tr\{(I-P)\} = tr\{I\} - tr\{P\} = n - tr\{X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\} = n - tr\{(X^TX)^{-1}X^TX\} = n - tr\{I_q\} = n - q$.

Therefore $E[\hat{E}^T\hat{E}] = \sigma_0^2 (n - q)$.

Then $E[\frac{\hat{E}^T\hat{E}}{n-q}] = \frac{\sigma_0^2 (n - q)}{(n-q)} = \sigma_0^2$

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response. Although perhaps I wasn't clear with my question (as I wouldn't be able to define $u$ as nx1 since I have p response variables). 
So I can't define $\hat{E}$ as you have but I can define one component of the matrix to that. I'm sure the extension to multivariate follows the same procedure.
This will help a lot in solving the multivariate case.

:)

Comment: Oh shoot. I see where the difficulty lays. I can't say that $$\hat{E}^T\hat{E} = tr(\hat{E}^T\hat{E})$$

Hmm...Perhaps taking the expectation will help somehow. I'll give it another go.

Comment: Oh wait..unless we write it as $$E= \begin{pmatrix}
        e_`^T \\
        \vdots \\
        e_n^T \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Wait. Now I'm confused about why you say $I-H$ is a constant.

Comment: I followed your work but need help proving that $var[u] = \sigma^2_0$? I'm not sure how the error matrix is distributed. It's supposed to be nxp.

Comment: There is an $I$ missing in $Var[u] = \sigma_0^2$ since $u$ is a vector.